# Windows Error 126 when importing xgboost into Anaconda

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, python-import, xgboost

Although I have been using Python for a while, I am relatively new to Anaconda, and package handling in general seems to cause a lot of problems for me.

I am trying to get xgboost up and running with Anaconda. I eventually managed to install it by using the command:

`conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost`

in the Anaconda prompt.

When I now try `import xgboost` in the PyCharm Python Console, I am given the following error:

```
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, May  1 2018, 18:37:09) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Backend Qt5Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Richard\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xgboost\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .core import DMatrix, Booster
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Richard\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 115, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()
  File "C:\Users\Richard\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 109, in _load_lib
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
  File "C:\Users\Richard\Anaconda2\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 444, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\Richard\Anaconda2\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 366, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I have searched for similar questions on StackOverflow, but I've had no luck, besides finding complicated answers which I did not feel comfortable implementing without fully understanding, and which I am not sure are applicable to my scenario anyway.

Some further things to note, which may be related:

- Originally, I installed the package using `pip install xgboost` in the Pycharm Terminal before realising my mistake.
- When I initially tried testing the xgboost package, I did so (stupidly) in a file named xgboost.py. I have since deleted this project. I uninstalled and reinstalled xgboost afterwards.
- I have tried several things to try and resolve this issue which may have complicated things further. For example, I deleted the 'xgboost' folder from inside 'C:\Users\Richard\Anaconda2' when typing `conda uninstall xgboost` into the Anaconda prompt failed.

Would anyone be able to shed any light on what is causing this issue? This is my first question on stack overflow, so I apologise if my question has not been posed completely correctly with regards to the guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further searching, I managed to answer my own question.

The xgboost (C++) library must be compiled and built before it can be used as a Python module. To do so, I carefully followed the instructions on this page:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_For_Anaconda_on_Windows?lang=en

and now, I think, xgboost is working fine. This is the first time I have encountered a package where this was required, hence the confusion. Hopefully this will help someone else who has the same issue.